# Is there a Debian trackpad configuration to prevent mouse moving when tapping or drag release?

Tags: debian, touchpad

I'm trying to fine tune my debian/xfce4 environment.

For some reason i'm used to moving with one finger and clicking with another. I think this helps when I need to drag something a long distance. The problem is when i have my cursor positioned in a specific location with my index finger, and it doesn't move, then i press to click with my thumb, just barely touching with mt thumb makes the cursor move. This is on a macbook, and I'm migrating from macos where I used to do this all the time without any problems.

It also seems like sometimes when i place my thumb on, just before I click in a scrollable window, it will cause the window to scroll. This one i'm thinking might just be a matter of adjusting the sensitivity.

I looked in the synaptics options available, but I couldn't find anything that looks right.

Comment: Consider trying xserver-xorg-input-libinput instead?

Comment: It looks like both xserver-xorg-input-libinput and xserver-xorg-input-synaptics are installed, could that be part of the problem? or do i need to configure it to use one over the other?